# File path validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate XML file path in javascript. My REGEX is:

```
var isValid = /^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\{2}|\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\\s_@-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+(\\{2}|\/)?)+(\.xml+)?$/.test(str);
```

It returns true even when path is wrong.
These are valid paths

```
D:/test.xml
D:\\folder\\test.xml
D:/folder/test.xml
D:\\folder/test.xml
D:\\test.xml
```

Comment: would be helpful if you say which path should not be valid. i assume it should always end with an xml file. but is the `D:/` required ? or is also a path starting with `/` valid ?

Comment: There can be any character instead of D. But it should end on .xml

Comment: sorry was unclear about it. is the driver letter required in a valid path or would `/folder/test.xml` also be valid ?

Comment: yeah drive letter is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**At first the obvious errors:**

`+` is a repeat indicator that has the meaning at least one.
so the `(\.xml+)` will match everything starting with `.xm` followed by one or more `l` (it would also match `.xmlllll`). the `?` means optional, so `(\.xml+)?` has the meaning it could have an `.xml` but it is not required.

the same is for `([a-zA-Z]:)?` this means the driver letter is optional.

**Now the not so obvious errors**

`[a-zA-Z0-9\\s_@-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]` here you define a list of allowed chars. you have `\\s` and i assume you want to allow spaces, but this allows `\` and `s` so you need to change it to `\s`. then you have this part `@-^` i assume you want to allow `@`, `-` and `^` but the `-` has a special meaning inside of `[` `]`  with it you define a range so you allow all chars that are in the range of  `@` to `^`  if you want to allow `-` you need to escape it there so you have to write `@\-^` you also need to take care about `^`, if it is right after the `[` it would have also a special meaning.

**your Regex should contain the following parts:**

- `^[a-z]:` start with (`^`) driver letter
- `((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+` followed by one or more path parts that start with either `\` or `/` and having a path name containing one or more of your defined letters (`a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]`)
- `\.xml$` ends with (`$`)  the `.xml`

therefore your final regex should look like this
`/^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i.test(str)`
(under the assumption you do a case insensitve regex using the `i` flag)

**EDIT:**

```
var path1 = "D:/test.xml";               // D:/test.xml
var path2 = "D:\\folder\\test.xml";      // D:\folder\test.xml
var path3 = "D:/folder/test.xml";        // D:/folder/test.xml
var path4 = "D:\\folder/test.xml";       // D:\folder/test.xml
var path5 = "D:\\test.xml";              // D:\test.xml

console.log( /^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i.test(path1) );
console.log( /^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i.test(path2) );
console.log( /^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i.test(path3) );
console.log( /^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i.test(path4) );
console.log( /^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i.test(path5) );
```

**UPDATE:**

you need to take care about the `/` and the `\` if you need to escape them depends on if you use it with `new RegExp(' ... the regex ... ',"i")` and `new RegExp("  ... the regex ... ","i")` or with `/  ... the regex ...  /i`

for further informations about regular expressions you should take a look at e.g. [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: update regex for this path too. var path4 = "D:\folder\folder/test.xml";

Comment: @ImranTariq  `"D:\folder\folder/test.xml"`  is not  `D:\folder\folder/test.xml`  `\f` is like `\n` or `\r` a special char ... check `console.log("\f".length)` which has the length of 1 and is not `\ `  +  `f`

Comment: I mean path may contain one backslash \ i.e. D:\folder\folder/test.xml

Comment: @ImranTariq one backslash: `"D:\\name.xml"` two backslashes: `"D:\\\\name.xml"` no backslash, but a newline (`\n`): `"D:\name.xml"`. (you need to escape backslashes in strings with a backslash !)

Comment: regex fails if folder name contains dots. fixed regex `/^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!.#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.xml$/i`

Answer (score 0):

This could work out for you

```
var str = 'D:/test.xml';
var str2 = 'D:\\folder\\test.xml';
var str3 = 'D:/folder/test.xml';
var str4 = 'D:\\folder/test.xml';
var str5 = 'D:\\test\\test\\test\\test.xml';

var regex = new RegExp('^[a-z]:((\\\\|\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_ \-]+)+\.xml$', 'i'); 
regex.test(str5);
```

The reason of having `\\\\` in RegExp to match a `\\` in string is that javascript uses `\` to escape special characters, i.e., `\n` for new lines, `\b` for word boundary etc. So to use a literal `\`, use `\\`. It also allows you to have different rules for file name and folder name.

### Update

`[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+` this section of regexp actually match file/folder name. So to allow more characters in file/folder name, just add them to this class, e.g., to allow a `*` in file/folder name make it `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\*]+`

### Update 2

For adding to the answer, following is an RegExp that adds another check to the validation, i.e., it checks for mixing of `/` and `\\` in the path.

```
var str6 = 'D:/This is folder/test @ file.xml';
var str7 = 'D:/This is invalid\\path.xml'
var regex2 = new RegExp('^[a-z]:(\/|\\\\)([a-zA-Z0-9_ \-]+\\1)*[a-zA-Z0-9_ @\-]+\.xml?', 'gi');
```

`regex2` will match all paths but `str7`

### Update

My apologies for mistyping a `?` instead of `$` in `regex2`. Below is the corrected and intended version

```
var regex2 = new RegExp('^[a-z]:(\/|\\\\)([a-zA-Z0-9_ \-]+\\1)*[a-zA-Z0-9_ @\-]+\.xml$', 'i');
```

Comment: This also validates 'D:/testxml' i.e. no dot before xml

Answer (score 0):

Tested using Scratchpad.

```
var regex = /^[a-z]:((\/|(\\?))[\w .]+)+\.xml$/i;
```

Prints `true` in Web Console: (Ctrl+Shift+K on Firefox)

```
console.log(regex.test("D:/test.xml"));
console.log(regex.test("D:\\folder\\test.xml"));
console.log(regex.test("D:/folder/test.xml"));
console.log(regex.test("D:\\folder/test.xml"));
console.log(regex.test("D:\\test.xml"));
console.log(regex.test("D:\\te st_1.3.xml")); // spaces, dots allowed
```

Or, using Alert boxes:

```
alert(regex.test("D:/test.xml"));
alert(regex.test("D:\\folder\\test.xml"));
alert(regex.test("D:/folder/test.xml"));
alert(regex.test("D:\\folder/test.xml"));
alert(regex.test("D:\\test.xml"));
alert(regex.test("D:\\te st_1.3.xml"));
```

Invalid file paths:

```
alert(regex.test("AD:/test.xml")); // invalid drive letter
alert(regex.test("D:\\\folder\\test.xml")); // three backslashes
alert(regex.test("/folder/test.xml")); // drive letter missing
alert(regex.test("D:\\folder/test.xmlfile")); // invalid extension
```

Comment: @ImranTariq Rewrote regex using JavaScript style case-insensitive flag.

Comment: Is your input one single file path or a bunch of them each on a new line?