# Validate String input COULD be a valid path

Tags: java, file

I wish to validate a string path. I don't want to check that the path exists or create the path (that includes create + then delete), I simply wish to check that the input string COULD be a validate path on the executing system.

So far I have been messing with the `File` class with no luck. I would expect the following to fail on my OSX machine but it doesn't:

```
File f = new File("!@£$%^&*()±§-_=+[{}]:;\"'|>.?/<,~`±");
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

Is there anything that will do this for me?

Comment: `I simply wish to check that the input string COULD be a validate path on the executing system.` What's the end goal?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - to validate the user has actually inputted something which adheres to the operating system's rules of how a path can be constructed.

Comment: In your example, couldn't that be a valid file path?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - oh my, I stand corrected, I thought that would be invalid - its not!!

Comment: There's very little that isn't allowed in a file name, on unix systems at least.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - added a definitely invalid example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via regex: [File path validation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231210/file-path-validation-in-javascript)

Or by checking if the parent of the path exists: [Is there a way in Java to determine if a path is valid without attempting to create a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468789/is-there-a-way-in-java-to-determine-if-a-path-is-valid-without-attempting-to-cre)

Just note that the path depends on the OS: https://serverfault.com/questions/150740/linux-windows-unix-file-names-which-characters-are-allowed-which-are-unesc

Also, just because the path is valid, it doesn't mean the file can be written there. For example, in Linux, you need to be a super user to write to /usr/

Comment: Please don't put link only answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to use regex to check the path. Regex would look like:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$
```

And an example can be seen [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com/392p5). You can check this in `Java` using the `String.matches(regex)` function. An example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String regex = "^(?:[a-zA-Z]\\:|\\\\\\\\[\\w\\.]+\\\\[\\w.$]+)\\\\(?:[\\w]+\\\\)*\\w([\\w.])+$";
    String path = "c:\\folder\\myfile.txt";

    System.out.println(path.matches(regex));

}
```

(*Note that the regex looks significantly longer due to having to escape the `\` characters*). Just call `yourPathString.matches(regex)`, and it will return true if it is a valid path.

Comment: This looks like a windows only solution. I need platform independence.

Comment: It matches linux/Mac paths as well. Check the regexr demo and test the paths you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

If the path is valid, then at least one of the chain of parent files must exist.  If no parent exists, then it must be invalid.

```
public static boolean isValidPath(File file) throws IOException {
    file = file.getCanonicalFile();

    while (file != null) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        }

        file = file.getParentFile();
    }

    return false;
}

System.out.println(isValidPath(new File("/Users/something")));  // true (OS X)
System.out.println(isValidPath(new File("asfq34fawrf")));  // false
```

Comment: What if it's a relative path?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited the answer.  It would need to be converted to an absolute path.

Comment: With your solution, if it is a relative path, it is resolved against the current working directory. It will then be valid, since the parent file exists, since the pwd exists. Even if the file name is not acceptable.

Comment: This FAILS on my example in the OP regardless of whether its an absolute or relative path.