# folder path validation in javascript/regex

Tags: javascript

I need to validate folder path with having forward(/)slash

regex or javascript code should validate and allow below format path only.

ex1:  "D:/dir1/dir2/dir3"

ex2:  "c:/dirname1/somedir/dirname/batch.log"

ex3:  "E:/user/desktop/somedir/fname.csv"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File path validation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231210/file-path-validation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
regx: '/^(?:[\w]\:|\/)(\/[A-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+/g'

With version: '^(?:[\w]\:|\/)(\/[A-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$'
```

Expalnation :**^(?:[\w]:|/) -- Begin with x:/ or //**

**[A-z_-\s0-9.] -- valid characters are a-z| 0-9|-|.|_ (you can add more)**

**(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx) -- Valid extension (you can add more)**

Comment: frustrateddeveloper,

Above solution is working fine. but now I need colon( : ) optional.
for ex
"c:/dirname1/somedir/dirname/batch.log",

or

"c/dirname1/somedir/dirname/batch.log"

could you please help me here to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

**I think this will works:**

```
 var pattern = "[(c|C|D|d|E|e)]:.*";
 var str = "E:/dir1/dir2/dir3";
 var result = str.match(pattern);
```

Comment: No Gnana paths can be..

D:/Inventory/Verizon/CVGRPT,  
 

D:/Inventory/Verizon/batch_reports/missing-report.csv

Comment: @shashikeshari I updated my answer please check now